# Is serverfault.daytorrents.com a phishing site?

Tags: support, serverfault, password

Today, I thought I was on https://serverfault.com but Google had actually sent me to https://serverfault.daytorrents.com/.

That site looks exactly like Server Fault, except that I couldn't comment because I was not logged in. Then I tried to login, but it didn't work. After a few tries, I realized I was on the wrong domain.

So serverfault.daytorrents.com certainly looks and behaves exactly like a phishing site. I immediately changed my password on the real Server Fault site, but I would still like to know.

Comment: They have your password now. You should change it. And change it wherever else you reused that password.

Comment: @wont : maybe you should read posts before commenting... :-)

Comment: I've read it three times. You seem to suggest you attempted to log into serverfault.daytorrents.com. To quote, *"Then I tried to login, but it didn't work. After a few tries, I realized I was on the wrong domain."* So you just handed the wrong domain your login information. Or, at least, it's reasonable to assume they have it. Thus my comment. You are of course welcome to take it under advisement or tell me to take a hike. But you should probably change that password on whatever domains you've used them.

Comment: @wont: Yes, I did try to login. That is why, as the last sentence in my post says:  "I immediately changed my password on the real Server Fault site". Maybe you don't need to read stuff 3 times. Just one time but until the end :-) . But anyway, for others who may come across this, it can only be good to insist on the need to change the password in such cases.